# Image not present in validated_data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

#### The problem:

I'm trying to implement a Serializer that serializes a Profile model. Unfortunately, the `image` key and its value are not present in `validated_data` passed to the `update()` method of the serializer.

---

#### The setup:

This is the environment I'm testing this on:
`Django 1.11.4`, `djangorestframework 3.6.3`, `Python 3.6.5`

This is the request I'm using to PUT to the respective endpoint:

```
curl -vvv \
     -XPUT \
     -H "Authorization:Bearer ${accessToken}" \
     -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
     -F "user=http://${baseURL}/users/2;type=application/json" \
     -F "image=@${image1};type=image/png" \
     ${url}
```

The serializer code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image',)

    image = serializers.ImageField(required=True)


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'url',
            'user',
            'image',
            )

    image = ImageSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # The documentation tells me it should now work like this:
        uploaded_image = validated_data.pop('image')
        instance.image = ProfileImage.objects.create(image=uploaded_image)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
        # but validated_data.pop('image') raises a KeyError which is logical, 
        # since validated_data does not contain an 'image' key.
```

The model code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ProfileImage(Image):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), related_name='profile')
    image = models.OneToOneField(ProfileImage, related_name='profile', null=True, default=None)
```

When I set a breakpoint inside the `update()` method of the serializer and inspect `validated_data`, the image key value pair is not present, which is why `validated_data.pop('image')` (as proposed [in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)) raises a KeyError.

---

#### A possible workaround?

I can however retrieve the image from the request data like this and update the model manually:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    uploaded_image = self.context.get('request').data.get('image')
    instance.image = ProfileImage.objects.create(image=uploaded_image)
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

However, this seems quite hacky to me since I suppose there must be some way to get the image to be present in `validated_data` as well.

---

#### The question(s):

- Is the proposed manual method acceptable or is it a bad hack?
- Why is the image key value pair not present in validated_data?
- Should it be present?

---

#### What I've tried so far:

I've implemented a `validate()` override in the ProfileSerializer, inspected the `attrs` that were passed to it, image wasn't in there.

I've implemented `validate_image()` on both the ProfileSerializer and the ImageSerializer, none of which were invoked.

I've implemented a `validate()` and an `update()` override in the ImageSerializer, none of which were invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the name `image` in the request did not match the nested field name `image.image`.

Since the [field name didn't match, `Serializer.get_value()` returns 'empty'](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f148e4e2593e55c76c746c85422924c33ec435cc/rest_framework/serializers.py#L421),
which leads to `Serializer.to_internal_value()` skipping [the field entirely](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f148e4e2593e55c76c746c85422924c33ec435cc/rest_framework/serializers.py#L496).

Basically, the body part was just ignored silently.

To get it working, I had to change the request to this:

```
curl -vvv \
     -XPUT \
     -H "Authorization:Bearer ${accessToken}" \
     -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
     -F "user=http://${baseURL}/users/2;type=application/json" \
     -F "image.image=@${image1};type=image/png" \
     ${url}
```

Answer (score -1):

From [Django Rest Framework's documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):

> By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support
>   write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create
>   create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how
>   the child relationships should be saved.

In your example, you should update the related object by hand in your `update` method:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    if 'image' in validated_data:
        instance.image.image = validated_data.pop('image')
    ...

    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: That's a nice answer, but my actual question is why 'image' is not present in validated_data (which it isn't, unfortunately). I've tried to clarify the question a bit.